# Does something like a github tool belt exist?

Tags: github

Basically, I'd like to gather a list of links to github repos, and be able to flick through a list if readmes. Anyone know of anything that does this?

Comment: Where is the programming code and question? Maybe Google can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GitHub's Web API](http://developer.github.com/).

I'll demonstrate with the [Spoon-Knife](https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife) repo:

First, you make a request to get the readme file(ofcourse, replace `octocat/Spoon-Knife` with the username&reponame you need):

```
$ curl "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/readme"
{
  "type": "file",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/blob/master/README",
  "_links": {
    "html": "https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/blob/master/README",
    "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/git/blobs/c8f68c2fd5a340b5ec89ada61984254e31c6785d",
    "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/contents/README"
  },
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/contents/README",
  "path": "README",
  "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/git/blobs/c8f68c2fd5a340b5ec89ada61984254e31c6785d",
  "content": "QWxsIHRoYXQncyBtaXNzaW5nIGlzIHRoZSBmb3JrLiBIZWgu\n",
  "sha": "c8f68c2fd5a340b5ec89ada61984254e31c6785d",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "size": 36,
  "name": "README"
}
```

Notice the `html_url` field - that's the HTML link to the file in the GitHub Web-GUI display. But since you only want the contents of the file, you'll need to change `blob` to `raw`:

```
$ curl "https://raw.github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/master/README"
All that's missing is the fork. Heh.
```

Ofcourse, you would probably want to use the HTTP facilities of whatever programming language you are using instead of `curl` to query the GitHub server.

**EDIT**

Instead of making additional GET request, you can decode the `content` field using a base64 decoder:

```
$ echo QWxsIHRoYXQncyBtaXNzaW5nIGlzIHRoZSBmb3JrLiBIZWgu | base64 --decode
All that's missing is the fork. Heh.
```